# Anybody had much experience with using the accelerometer on iOS devices inside phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Anybody had much experience with using the accelerometer on iOS devices inside phonegap?

Basically on shaking the iOS device I need to call a function.

Matt.

Answer (score 0):

I am using accelerometer for a test project, and seems to work fine (on both iOS and Android), though I am not implementing any shake handling yet. There are several articles with possible detection algorithms, but this one is posted on PhoneGap WIKI, so probably a good place to start: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494783/Handling%20Shake%20Events